# What is React's earliest lifecycle event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that I wish to install into the `window.app` variable as soon as possible, so that nested components can reference it **as they mount**. Now, outside of React, I would normally do this on the first line in `window.onload()` and I am wondering where the earliest possible spot is when using React *which I am now learning*.

I was using the App's `componentDidMount` method but the nested components fired their own `componentDidMount` first; App's `componentDidMount` seems to be last. Then I found this [helpful lifecycle chart](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) and I am now using App's `constructor` which is console logging before the nested components, so that's an improvement.

Is App's `constructor` the earliest spot we can write code?

Comment: its not a good idea to set any variable to window in react unless its absolutely required. Its best to pass on that variable to the component as a prop.

Comment: Well, its much more than a variable, its an object (class instance) which is modifying how localStorage will be used throughout the React app. Specifically, when a component interacts with localStorage, it will not call `localStorage` directly, but rather `window.app.setStorage`. You can see a [demonstration of the idea here](https://jcode.me/overcoming-5mb-of-localstorage-with-lzw-compression/).

Comment: Why not just make a component for that which will have the set and get methods and use localstorage in there? import this component only where you need them. This will avoid using the window object all together.

Comment: Yes, now **that** does sound better than having to pass it through `props` everywhere. It keeps it modular and in React's ecosystem. I will try this - thank you.

Comment: Will update this as the answer, so that others can also take this suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to execute as early as possible and does not depend on react, probably keep it outside the react ecosystem altogether and set it before the `ReactDOM.render` method that bootstraps the react application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by  _"set it before"_ the [ReactDOM.render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) method? Its an interesting idea; how do I get in front of the bootstrapping?

Comment: just put it in index.js like so : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lfkrjg

Comment: Got it, thank you. I see now I was trying to do things "the React way", but you are right, nothing will be earlier than loading the variable before React renders.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, Its not a good idea to directly set variable to the window object unless absolutely necessary.

Instead, a better approach would be to just pass the variable down as a prop.

As per your comment,

> Well, its much more than a variable, its an object (class instance)
>   which is modifying how localStorage will be used throughout the React
>   app. Specifically, when a component interacts with localStorage, it
>   will not call localStorage directly, but rather window.app.setStorage.
>   You can see a demonstration of the idea [here](https://jcode.me/overcoming-5mb-of-localstorage-with-lzw-compression/).

A better approach would be to just make a component for that which will have the set and get methods and use localstorage in the component. Import this component only where you need them. This will avoid using the window object all together and also keep your code much readable.